# Role-based authentification for the WCF REST service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, rest

I am trying to implement role-based authentification to the REST WCF service . I read a lot of information on this theme but didn't got a clear understanding of what I have to do.
I understand how to restrict an access to the service using the [PrincipalPermission] attribute but don't know how to check whether the user belong to the certain role or not.
Therefore I will be very grateful if somebody can direct me to the right way (e.g. make a roadmap what should I do to achive this goal).

Let me describe this situation. I have a remote services which hosted on the server A and ASP.Net MVC client hosted on the server B.
All of these rest services has an access to the database where I can read an information whether the user has access to the service or not.

Comment: We probably need more information about the nature of your project. For instance, if it's a web server you're creating and you're planning to make it public, there's no way (that I know of) to somehow capture the "role" of some anonymous users coming in. Thus you'd be stuck checking values against a database to determine a role. However, if you're using a TCPIP binding with network users, you might be able to get roles with a call to your LDAP server. But we need more info ...

Comment: All my services should be located on the Internet. Each of these services is working with confidential information. So I have to restrict access to these services in accordance with the user role .
All information about users , roles, and services stored in database.

Comment: As a platform for creating services I use WCF. Since it's REST services , I use webHttpBinding.

interaction between the client and the service is performed in the following manner.
I have an ASP.Net MVC project (which acts as a client ) . User authorizing on the site and trying to invoke the remote service. When he trying to call service, the service should check whether the user has access to to this REST service or not?

Answer (score 0):

OK, Tequila, IMO what you really want, based on your description, is a normal, REST WCF service with a Login(ID as string, PWD as string) method that (perhaps) returns a SessionID. This Login() or SessionID() check method would then preceed access to all of your other methods. And since it's a webHTTPBinding -- effectively a stateless web service -- you'll need to check the SessionID or ID/Password before each request is processed.

So the workflow would be something like this:

```
1) client sends Login() request to host
2) host checks ID/Password against DB, creates SessionID in DB that times out after x hours, forcing new Login(). SessionID is returned in response to client,.
3) In all subsequent requests, client must provide that SessionID. That SessionID would be checked on the DB, returning stored information about the client (Role, name, ID, address ... whatever is useful) before the remainder of the request is processed.
```

There are methods for authenticating users BEFORE the request gets to your working code (like client authentication using Forms or client certificates (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff405740.aspx)). This shifts the Login() / SessionID check to a method executed BEFORE the request hits your main program, but the steps are basically the same.

And since passing ID/Pwd in clear text over the web is a no-no, you'd want to implement SSL on your web service (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650785.aspx)

Everything I've describe is basically platform independent, so if you'll have iOS or Android clients, there's nothing in what I've described that would prohibit those OSs from successfully interacting with your web service.

Good luck.